# 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError

Tags: python, http, networking, https, mozilla

While installing any package for python in pycharm. Getting below error:-
Collecting py2neo

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb8e2e15780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /simple/py2neo/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb8e2e155f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /simple/py2neo/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb8e2e15898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /simple/py2neo/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb8e2e154a8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /simple/py2neo/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb8e2e15400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /simple/py2neo/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py2neo (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for py2neo
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are connected and internet is working.

Answer (score 4):

I am experiencing exactly the same errors inside my Docker container, behind corporate Proxy. no matter which package I am trying to install.

**I could nail it down to the following:**

I am getting this error as soon as any proxy env var is set (either https_proxy or HTTPS_PROXY). The curious thing it doesn´t matter if this is the right proxy or not. Also, I experienced, that when one of these vars is set, pip seems to ignore what I pass via the --proxy switch during installation.

**I got it working using the following workaround:**

1. making sure that there is neither https_proxy (lowercase), not HTTPS_PROXY (uppercase) environment var is set.
2. run pip install using the following command

```sh
pip3 --proxy=http://<proxyHost>:<proxyPort> install  py2neo
```

While this workaround works for me, I would still be interested to find a resolution for this, as

1. I am really curious about what´s going there
2. it is kind of annoying to have to specify the proxy in the command inside of the Dockerfile

Comment: I also seem to have the issue that HTTPS_PROXY env variable overwrites anything I pass with --proxy=...

Comment: This. I had `http_proxy https_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY` all set using export, but it didn't even work when `pip --proxy=...` was specified. `unset http_proxy https_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY` and then specify proxy only in `pip --proxy=...`.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning, I had a pip.ini file in c:\users\me\pip\pip.ini which held the proxy info. I had to trash this in order to fix this.